# How can I make a jQuery infinite carousel.. finite?

Tags: jquery

here's the source code:

```
/**
 * @author Stéphane Roucheray 
 * @extends jquery
 */


jQuery.fn.carousel = function(previous, next, options){
    var sliderList = jQuery(this).children()[0];

    if (sliderList) {
        var increment = jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth("true"),
        elmnts = jQuery(sliderList).children(),
        numElmts = elmnts.length,
        sizeFirstElmnt = increment,
        shownInViewport = Math.round(jQuery(this).width() / sizeFirstElmnt),
        firstElementOnViewPort = 1,
        isAnimating = false;

        for (i = 0; i < shownInViewport; i++) {
            jQuery(sliderList).css('width',(numElmts+shownInViewport)*increment + increment + "px");
            jQuery(sliderList).append(jQuery(elmnts[i]).clone());
        }

        jQuery(previous).click(function(event){
            if (!isAnimating) {
                if (firstElementOnViewPort == 1) {
                    jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "-" + numElmts * sizeFirstElmnt + "px");
                    firstElementOnViewPort = numElmts;
                }
                else {
                    firstElementOnViewPort--;
                }

                jQuery(sliderList).animate({
                    left: "+=" + increment,
                    y: 0,
                    queue: true
                }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
                isAnimating = true;
            }

        });

        jQuery(next).click(function(event){
            if (!isAnimating) {
                if (firstElementOnViewPort > numElmts) {
                    firstElementOnViewPort = 2;
                    jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "0px");
                }
                else {
                    firstElementOnViewPort++;
                }
                jQuery(sliderList).animate({
                    left: "-=" + increment,
                    y: 0,
                    queue: true
                }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
                isAnimating = true;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Can someone point me in a right direction on how to make it finite? For example, you have 4 blocks and when you scroll to the last one - next button stopping to work only the previous one.

Comment: Carousels spin around forever. Sounds like you don't want a carousel...

Comment: Yes i know, but it's almost the same as i want but not infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to look into removing:

```
jQuery(sliderList).append(jQuery(elmnts[i]).clone());
```

This is the line that takes an element and puts it into the end of the queue.

To prevent effect of clicking `next/previous` you can use this "hack":

```
// Save 'snownInViewport' value right before "for" cycle
sliderList.data("shownInViewport", shownInViewport);
for (i = 0; i < shownInViewport; i++) {
```

In `previous` click handler:

```
if (firstElementOnViewPort == 1) {
    return;
    //jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "-" + numElmts * sizeFirstElmnt + "px");
    //firstElementOnViewPort = numElmts;
}
```

In `next` click handler:

```
if (firstElementOnViewPort + sliderList.data("shownInViewport") > numElmts) {
    return;
    //firstElementOnViewPort = 2;
    //jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "0px");
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's disabling the infinite loop, however, if i have 4 blocks and you'll go beyond 4th block it will slide further with empty blocks until the 4th block is totally dissapeared, take a look here please: http://dima.webcoder.kz/probnyi-material-0  HOW TO MAKE next or previous button non clickable or something like that when you're on the last block?

Comment: Please try updated answer.

Comment: still scrolls further

Comment: I managed to reproduce, one moment, let me play around a bit.

Comment: I've updated the answer again, should have been a bit different comparison.

Comment: After these changes - when i click next or previous zero reaction.

Comment: I might be a bit off (+-1), since I can't really run or debug it on your site :)
Could you try running my updated code in the page inspector (or firebug) and see what's the value of `firstElementOnViewPort` and `sliderList.data("shownInViewport")` when you click `next`?

Comment: Added your corrections can u check now please?

Comment: Ah... you need to use `jQuery(sliderList)` instead of `sliderList` when using `data()`